# ng-repeat syntax not correct

Tags: angularjs, syntax

I have a parse syntax error when i try this :

```
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts" id="{{post.idFB}}">                    
        <p>{{post.name}}</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="feed in feed{{post.idFB}}">
               <p>{{feed.title}}</p>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </div>
```

problem is the line `<li ng-repeat="feed in feed{{post.idFB}}">`, what is the good syntax ?

result expected is like feed846097918756247

The online app: http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/pmr/

EDIT : jmb.mage solution :

```
    <ul ng-init="myFeed = myFeedFunction(raterie.idFB);">
        <li ng-repeat="feed in myFeed | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feed846097918756247 | limitTo:1">search is : {{feed.title}}</li>
    <ul>
```

only second li works, not the first with the automatically variable

Comment: Not sure what you'r trying to do. Try this                               <li ng-repeat="feed in feed">
               <p>{{feed.title}}</p>
            </li>

Comment: $scope.feed doesn't exists.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with feed{{post.idFB}}

Comment: result expected is like feed846097918756247

Comment: see my app : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/pmr/ (with some differents param's names)

Answer (score 0):

If `feed846097918756247` is a JavaScript object than you could do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" id="{{post.idFB}}">                    
    <p>{{post.name}}</p>
    <ul ng-init="var myFeed = eval('feed' + post.idFB);">
        <li ng-repeat="feed in myFeed">
           <p>{{feed.title}}</p>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Although since it's using `eval()`, you may need to do the ng-init with a function like:
 `<ul ng-init="var myFeed = myFeedFunction(post.idFB);">`
and then have a function in your controller:

```
function myFeedFunction(pId) {
    return eval('feed' + pId) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use only a feed object as follow, scope.feed[scope.posts[index].idFB]= 'whatever'

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" id="{{post.idFB}}">                    
    <p>{{post.name}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feed[post.idFB]">
           <p>{{feed.title}}</p>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: seems solution doesn't working : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/pmr/ $scope.feed846097918756247 is the example